# Assign a name for each unique value in another column

Tags: r, unique, assign

I have C1 in a df and would like to get an new column, C2, with an id, based on each unique value in C1.
But I would like to have a specific name for the C2 (*Group*) followed by a number, starting counting from 01 and not 1, as I will have up to 13 Groups and want to group them properly.
I would also like to keep the same name for the last unique value (Z), so that C2 looks like this:

```
   C1    C2     
   <chr> <chr>  
 1 A     Group01
 2 A     Group01
 3 A     Group01
 4 A     Group01
 5 B     Group02
 6 B     Group02
 7 B     Group02
 8 B     Group02
 9 C     Group03
10 C     Group03
11 C     Group03
12 C     Group03
13 Z     Z      
14 Z     Z      
15 Z     Z      
16 Z     Z
```

I have tried to get the id, e.g.
`df <- transform(df,id=as.numeric(factor(C1)))`
But I get this.

```
   C1      C2 id
1   A Group01  1
2   A Group01  1
3   A Group01  1
4   A Group01  1
5   B Group02  2
6   B Group02  2
7   B Group02  2
8   B Group02  2
9   C Group03  3
10  C Group03  3
11  C Group03  3
12  C Group03  3
13  Z       Z  4
14  Z       Z  4
15  Z       Z  4
16  Z       Z  4
```

I guess I could create a new column with the "Group" argument, but I don't know how to get an id starting from 01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` + `unique` to get a unique number for each `C1` value, keep the value same as `C1` for the last value in the group. Use `sprintf` to get value as 01.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
        mutate(tmp = match(C1, unique(C1)), 
               C2 = replace(sprintf('Group%02d', tmp), C1 == 'Z', 'Z')) %>%
        select(-tmp)
df

#   C1      C2
#1   A Group01
#2   A Group01
#3   A Group01
#4   A Group01
#5   B Group02
#6   B Group02
#7   B Group02
#8   B Group02
#9   C Group03
#10  C Group03
#11  C Group03
#12  C Group03
#13  Z       Z
#14  Z       Z
#15  Z       Z
#16  Z       Z
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(C1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z")), row.names = c(NA, -16L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It seems to work, but doesn't drop the tmp column. What is the part in the code that keeps the Z as Z in C2?

Comment: 1. You need to assign the data back to original `df` i.e `df <- df %>%mutate(....`. 2. `ifelse(tmp == max(tmp), C1...)` keeps Z as Z since Z will have `max` `tmp` value.

Comment: 1. yes, I have tried that but no success. Any ideas? I did this ```df <- subset(df, select = -c(tmp))``` and worked. 2. Ok. Could you please show an alternative, so that it keeps Z in C2, whenever it reads Z in C1?

Comment: I thought you want to keep whatever last unique value is present in your data. If you want to specifically keep 'Z' value I have updated the answer for that.

Comment: yes, that was an additional question. I sometimes have in C1 rows containing Z (e.g. Z or Z_samples etc), so I wanted to keep the same name in C2 whenever in C1 finds Z in the name. I thought about which function  ``` A tibble: 20 x 1
   C1       
   <chr>    
 1 A        
 2 A        
 3 A        
 4 A        
 5 B        
 6 B        
 7 B        
 8 B        
 9 C        
10 C        
11 C        
12 C        
13 Z        
14 Z        
15 Z        
16 Z        
17 Z_samples
18 Z_samples
19 Z_samples
20 Z_samples  ```

Comment: @catinstack Now you want to keep all the values in `C1` if there is `Z` anywhere in the name? In my current answer you can change the `replace` line to `C2 = ifelse(grepl('Z', C1), C1, sprintf('Group%02d', tmp)) %>%`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**  In that case you can use if_else statement

```
df <- data.frame(C1 = c(rep(LETTERS[1:7], each = 4), rep("Z", 4)))
df


df %>% mutate(C2 = if_else(C1 == "Z", C1, paste0("Group", str_pad(dense_rank(C1), width = 2, side = "left", pad = "0"))))

   C1      C2
1   A Group01
2   A Group01
3   A Group01
4   A Group01
5   B Group02
6   B Group02
7   B Group02
8   B Group02
9   C Group03
10  C Group03
11  C Group03
12  C Group03
13  D Group04
14  D Group04
15  D Group04
16  D Group04
17  E Group05
18  E Group05
19  E Group05
20  E Group05
21  F Group06
22  F Group06
23  F Group06
24  F Group06
25  G Group07
26  G Group07
27  G Group07
28  G Group07
29  Z       Z
30  Z       Z
31  Z       Z
32  Z       Z
```

OR if last value is not known

```
df %>% mutate(d = dense_rank(C1),
              C2 = if_else(d == max(d), C1, paste0("Group", str_pad(d, width = 2, side = "left", pad = "0")))) %>%
  select(-d)

   C1      C2
1   A Group01
2   A Group01
3   A Group01
4   A Group01
5   B Group02
6   B Group02
7   B Group02
8   B Group02
9   C Group03
10  C Group03
11  C Group03
12  C Group03
13  D Group04
14  D Group04
15  D Group04
16  D Group04
17  E Group05
18  E Group05
19  E Group05
20  E Group05
21  F Group06
22  F Group06
23  F Group06
24  F Group06
25  G Group07
26  G Group07
27  G Group07
28  G Group07
29  Z       Z
30  Z       Z
31  Z       Z
32  Z       Z
```

Comment: I get this error:Error: `cur_group_id()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.

Comment: this works, thanks. But it names Z as Group+number and I will need that when "Z" is present in C1 to keep it and not assign it another name